# match parameter in group wise from url using regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regular expression

```
/([A-Za-z]+_([A-Za-z]+|-?[A-Z0-9]+(\.[A_Z0-9]+)?|(?:_|:|:-|-[a-zA-Z]+|\.[a-zA-Z]+|[A-Z0-9a-z]+|=|\s|\?|\%|\.|!|#|\*)?)+(?=(,|\/)))+/g
```

It matches urls like this

```
http://sample.com/transform/demo.sample.com/fetch/c_crop,g_north,x_100,y_30,w_400,h_600/l_text:Arial-blue.ttf_50_bold:hello how r u?,w_100,bg_4px_solid_034444,e_brightness:40/l_fetch:AhadagduYbBHBbHbshbadad9878h==,w_70,x_-10,y_10/sample.jpg
```

**URL should be different every time.**

Now i want to match group wise like `c_crop,g_north,x_100,y_30,w_400,h_600` , `l_text:Arial-blue.ttf_50_bold:hello how r u?,w_100,bg_4px_solid_034444,e_brightness:40`,`l_fetch:AhadagduYbBHBbHbshbadad9878h==,w_70,x_-10,y_10`.

So basically how can i group parameter between `/`

Answer (score 1):

One option might be to use [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) and then to get the different parts you are looking for from [pathname](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/pathname) and [search](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/search).

Split those values on a `/` and then split on a `,`. Filter the collection for values that start with one or more times a lowercase a-z followed by an underscore, and then match 1 or more times any char except a comma

```
\b[a-z]+_[^,]+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kXToXG/1)

For example

```js
let s = `http://sample.com/transform/demo.sample.com/fetch/c_crop,g_north,x_100,y_30,w_400,h_600/l_text:Arial-blue.ttf_50_bold:hello how r u?,w_100,bg_4px_solid_034444,e_brightness:40/l_fetch:AhadagduYbBHBbHbshbadad9878h==,w_70,x_-10,y_10/sample.jpg`;
let url = new URL(s);
let coll =
  url.pathname.split('/')
  .concat(url.search.split("/"))
  .flatMap(s => s.split(","))
  .filter(i => /^[a-z]+_[^,]+$/.test(i));
console.log(coll);
```